Axum middleware -- how to retrieve Extensions data in a middleware fn
In my rust application, I am injecting an extension sc while creating the router object.
pub fn create_routes(sc: &ServiceConfig) -> Router {
    let api_routes = Router::new().nest("/", create_workflow_router());

    let router = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(welcome))
        .nest("/api", api_routes)
        .layer(Extension(sc.clone()))
        .layer(from_fn(jwt_validator))
        .layer(ServiceBuilder::new().layer(TraceLayer::new_for_http()));

    router
}

Within the middleware handler, I am tryinng to retrieve the object sc, but the code always goes to the else block, indicating there is no sc object in the request.
pub async fn jwt_validator(
    req: Request<axum::body::Body>,
    next: Next,
) -> Result<Response, StatusCode> {


      // Retrieve ServiceConfig from request extensions
    let sc = if let Some(Extension(sc)) = req.extensions().get::<Extension<ServiceConfig>>() {
        sc.clone()
    } else {
        trace!("ServiceConfig not found in extensions.");
        return Err(StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    };

    // Print the contents of SC.
    println!("SC: {:?}", sc);

    // print 
    return Ok(next.run(req).await);
    /*


However, I am able to receive it in the handler that follows this middleware.
pub async fn get_workflows(
    Query(params): Query<WorkflowQueryParams>,
    Extension(sc): Extension<ServiceConfig>,
    //Extension(dbc): Extension<DatabaseConnection>,
    //Extension(claims): Extension<Claims>,
) -> impl IntoResponse {
    // Retrieve the customer id from claims
    //let customer_id = Uuid::parse_str(&claims.sub).unwrap();

    // debug print service_config
    println!("SC: {:?}", sc);

    return Json("Hello");

this is the output..
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z TRACE axum::serve] connection 127.0.0.1:34734 accepted
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z DEBUG tower_http::trace::make_span] request; method=GET uri=/api/v1/workflows version=HTTP/1.1
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z TRACE tracing::span::active] -> request;
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z DEBUG tower_http::trace::on_request] started processing request
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z TRACE tracing::span::active] <- request;
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z TRACE tracing::span::active] -> request;
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z TRACE workflow_svc::middlewares::jwt_validator] ServiceConfig not found in extensions.
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z DEBUG tower_http::trace::on_response] finished processing request latency=0 ms status=500
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z ERROR tower_http::trace::on_failure] response failed classification=Status code: 500 Internal Server Error latency=0 ms
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z TRACE tracing::span::active] <- request;
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z TRACE tracing::span] -- request;
[2024-10-01T06:02:35Z TRACE tracing::span] -- request;

However, I am able to retrieve the SC object in a handler that follows the above middleware, if I comment out the else block and allow the request to pass through to the next handler.  Below is the output,
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z TRACE axum::serve] connection 127.0.0.1:38964 accepted
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z DEBUG tower_http::trace::make_span] request; method=GET uri=/api/v1/workflows version=HTTP/1.1
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z TRACE tracing::span::active] -> request;
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z DEBUG tower_http::trace::on_request] started processing request
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z TRACE tracing::span::active] <- request;
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z TRACE tracing::span::active] -> request;
SC: ServiceConfig { auth_enabled: false, jwt_secret: None, host: "localhost", port: 4001, dbc: SqlxPostgresPoolConnection }
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z DEBUG tower_http::trace::on_response] finished processing request latency=0 ms status=200
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z TRACE tracing::span::active] <- request;
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z TRACE tracing::span] -- request;
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z TRACE tracing::span::active] -> request;
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z TRACE tracing::span::active] <- request;
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z TRACE tracing::span] -- request;
[2024-10-01T06:09:04Z TRACE axum::serve] connection 127.0.0.1:38964 closed

I am wondering, if there is a way to capture and mutate the SC object indside the muiddleware fn, before it reached the handler.

To get an extension from middleware, you don't need the Extension wrapper when using .extensions(); just get the type itself:
if let Some(sc) = req.extensions().get::<ServiceConfig>() {
    ...
}

Or you can use the parameter-based extractors you are familiar with (as long as it is before req):
pub async fn jwt_validator(
    Extension(sc): Extension<ServiceConfig>,
    req: Request<axum::body::Body>,
    next: Next,
) -> Result<Response, StatusCode> {
    ...
}


Finally, found it by searching through internet (and not through any AI tool such as copilot or chatGpt).  These tools gave a wrong suggestion which kept me frustrated for two days, trying to figure out where things are going wrong.
if you are like me, here is the solution:

When we want to access any state in middleware fn (as against a handler fn), you need to use from_fn_with_state instead of 'from_fn`, something like this.

pub fn create_routes(sc: &ServiceConfig) -> Router {
    let api_routes = Router::new().nest("/", create_workflow_router());

    let router = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(welcome))
        .nest("/api", api_routes)
        .layer(Extension(sc.clone()))
        .layer(from_fn_with_state(sc.clone(),jwt_validator))
        .layer(ServiceBuilder::new().layer(TraceLayer::new_for_http()));

    router
}

In the middleware fn you add an extra param State(your_state) like so..
pub async fn jwt_validator(
    State(sc): State<ServiceConfig>,
    mut req: Request<axum::body::Body>,
    next: Next,
) -> Result<Response, StatusCode> {
  // you will be able to access the state
 trace!("State is: {:?}", sc);
  ...
}

